# Unversion/Delete files based on svn ignore list config

Tags: git, svn

The SVN/GIT ignore works great for helping you keep files from getting committed to version control pre commit.  My question is, what is the easiest way to make a repository compliant to the SVN ignore file, post commit?

Example: Multiple `~$xxx.xlsx` files, `debug.log` files, and "`_Preview`" folders are spread across multiple folders at multiple levels and need to be removed from the repository.  It would be nice if SVN had a command that referenced the ignore list and would stage the removal of everything that violated the ignore list for review and commit to remove.  Just [Unversion and add to ignore list](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion.html) or any other command usually is on a file by file basis or recursive just to subfolders from where the file exists but not adjacent or above.

Situation: A lot (A LOT) of files have made it into the repository and the ignore list was extended, especially to include `~*`.  I started writing a batch file to go through, but if something like Tortoise or even a batch file could use the SVN config ignore list and delete all files based on that it would be most helpful.  At the moment I am writing a batch file to delete them, using `For /R C:\temp\ %%G IN (*.bak) do Echo "%%G"` as example from [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) but then will open a commit window, select all the missing files, and mark as SVN delete (assume moderate to experienced SVN user).  The batch file has its quirks I am working through and I will have to manually port the config file parameters into batch file readable parts unless I want to build a parser.

Example using TortoiseSVN with SVN in the SVN config file:

```
### Section for configuring miscellaneous Subversion options.
[miscellany]
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### This can be bypassed. Ex. Right click directly on files to add.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
### .mine and .r#### are created upon a SVN conflict
### .git .base .local .remote .original *.orig are GIT conflict files
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
  *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db desktop.ini
  History __[Pp]reviews [Pp]roject?[Ll]ogs?for* [Dd]ebug.log ~*
  *.mine *.r[0-9] *.r[0-9][0-9] *.r[0-9][0-9][0-9] *.r[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] *.r[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
  *.svn *.git *.BASE *.LOCAL *.REMOTE *.original *.orig
```

Details on a SVN ignore file, mine is local on my machine I have not explored the server side as it seems to be on a file by file/repo by repo basis: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html#tsvn-dug-ignore-glob

Comment: You are talking abour SVN or git?

Comment: If your question isn't about batch files, and you're not asking for assistance with a specific batch file issue, please remove the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, and be a little more considerate to those people watching that tag, who have no knowledge or experience of [[tag:git]] or [[tag:svn]].

Comment: There is a TortoiseSVN-specific changelist called [ignore-on-commit](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html), which might be of interest for you. Or you apply the [`svn:needs-lock` property](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html) on the applicable files, perhaps using the [`svn:auto-props` property](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html)...

Comment: @Compo: I included the batch file because my original post says I started out using a batch file.  If someone has a batch file that answers my question, then that would be an acceptable answer.  I am referring to a *.bat file in Windows. If that is not correct or if you can help me with other etticut, let me know.  I see the tag was removed which is ok I guess.

Comment: @Jens: In theory both have this concept so I applied it to both GIT and SVN, but I tried to consolidate my question to succinctly apply to SVN, "My question is, what is the easiest way to make a repository compliant to the SVN ignore file post commit?"